# the equivalent of python's [:] in c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Here is part of program 'Trackbar as the Color Palette' in python which is include with opencv. I want to use it in c++.

My problem is the last line.

```
r = cv2.getTrackbarPos('R','image')
g = cv2.getTrackbarPos('G','image')
b = cv2.getTrackbarPos('B','image')
img[:] = [b,g,r]
```

Without this command I just have a black image.

Comment: All the Python code does is replace all indices of `img` with three new ones. To break this down in steps: Clear `img`, resize it to hold 3 elements, assign `b` to index 0, `g` to index 1 and `r` to index 2. I'm sure C++ can do those steps one way or another.

Comment: What does your c++ code look like? How is the rgb triplet stored?

Comment: What make you believe that most Python constructs have their C++ equivalent? And what C++ standard? I hope you are coding in at least C++11 ..... Which compiler, which operating system, which extra libraries (standard C++11 has no notion of images or colors)?

Comment: Vec3b img (b, g, r);

Comment: Can you show the C++ code you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to set all pixels of the `CV_8UC3` image `img` to the color given by `b`, `g` and `r`;

You can do this in OpenCV like:

```
img.setTo(Vec3b(b, g, r));
```

or equivalently:

```
img.setTo(Scalar(b, g, r));
```

---

In your code you're missing basically all the important parts:

- the infinite loop (so you exit the program without refreshing the image color)
- the assignment of the new color
- you are mixing obsolete C syntax and C++ syntax.

This is what you need:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Initialize a black image
    Mat3b imgScribble(256, 512, Vec3b(0,0,0));

    namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    createTrackbar("R", "Image", 0, 255);
    createTrackbar("G", "Image", 0, 255);
    createTrackbar("B", "Image", 0, 255);

    while (true)
    {
        int r = getTrackbarPos("R", "Image");
        int g = getTrackbarPos("G", "Image");
        int b = getTrackbarPos("B", "Image");

        // Fill image with new color
        imgScribble.setTo(Vec3b(b, g, r));

        imshow("Image", imgScribble);
        if (waitKey(1) == 27 /*ESC*/) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's ok to set b,g,r to img but my problem is can't see the result in out

Comment: @Mr.E check updated answer, and edit the content of your answer into the question and delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for std::for_each(). This code is untested. It is intended to show the concept, It might contain bugs:

```
// color type - use whatever you have
using color = std::array<char, 3>;

// prepare image, wherever you get that from
auto img = std::vector<color>{width * height, color{{0x00, 0x00, 0x00}}};

// define the color we want to have: white
char r = 0xff;
char g = 0xff;
char b = 0xff;

std::for_each(std::begin(img), std::end(img),
              [&](color& i){
                  i = {r, g, b};
              });
```

By choosing iterators different from `std::begin()` and `std::end()` you can of course select any slice of your vector.

Yes, the idioms in C++ are different to the ones in Python.

Comment: No, use C++ 11 range-based for loop instead, it is more up-to date and elegant than for_each.

Comment: @ErikAlapää That is true, whenever you want to iterate over the whole range. The downside of a range based for loop is, that it does not work out of the box with slices of a range. The question was on assigning slices of a range. That is the reason, why I have suggested `std::for_each()`, which is much more expressive for iterating slices than the standard for-loop.

Comment: True, I just looked at the actual code where you used the entire vector. To use range-based for with a vector slice, one could use boost::adaptors::sliced.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Yes, boost ranges is a very useful library. Another approach would be to hope for the best, that Eric Nieblers range-V3 Proposal will be accepted. Then e.g. `for( auto& c: img | sliced_view(12, 31))` would do the trick; pretty similar to boost range, btw.

Comment: there's no need for fancy stuff. OpenCV has already appropriate methods and data structures to deal with this.